# URL Appending instead of redirecting

Tags: python, django, backend

When I click the link on my HTML page, instead of redirecting to the clicked url it appends to the current one and displays an error (404). How can I solve this and redirect to the correct url?

HTML Table where the link is displayed:

```
                        {% for acesso in acessos_medicos %}       
                       
                            <tr class="linha-tabela">
                                <td>{{acesso.identificacao}}</td>
                                <td>{{acesso.status}}</td>
                                <td><a href="{{acesso.url}}">{{acesso.url}}</a></td>
                            </tr>

                        {% endfor %}
```

models.py:

```
    @property
    def url(self):
        return f'http:127.0.0.1:8000/exames/acesso_medico/{self.token}'
```

path in urls.py:

`path('acesso_medico/<str:token>', views.acesso_medico, name="acesso_medico")`

Comment: Share your views.py please

Comment: maybe you should check if you have `relative` URL or `absolute` URL and `if/else` to send correct URL to `HTML`. In Python code you could also try to use standard `urllib`

Comment: maybe you forgot `/` at the beginning of url - to create absolute url instead of relative url.

Comment: I didn't know about this relative/absolute url thing. I tried the `/` at the beggining but it didn't change anything, but I could make it work by changing the <a> tag in th HTML.  Instead of `<td><a href="{{acesso.url}}">{{acesso.url}}</a></td>`, I used `<td><a href="{% url 'acesso_medico' acesso.token %}">{{acesso.url}}</a></td>`. Thanks guys!!!